# rails STI: specific attributes for subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm starting building my first rails app and i already have user model with STI (admin, employee, public and representative all inherits from user model).
but now i want to add specific columns (adress, state, phone) for representative subclass but i cannot apply migration directly for subclass model.

- the first solution is to add these columns tu user model but i don't know how th restrict acess to only representant subclass
- the second solution is to create a separate contact table and and then use polymorphic association (i want to associate with other model) and add the attributes
- my question is what is the best solution for this case? and if there is better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you Doing well

I think second option is better then first.

Reason:
1) If this all filed are optional then it will create record with null value but in second case if all filed are optional then record will not be created,there is no need to any entry for that.

2) In future there is requirement of add or use this filed into other model then you can do by easily with polymorphic association .

Comment: Thank you, i'll use polymorphic association option but i'll wait sometime in case someone has another new option to suggest

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are abusing the idea of an STI in this case. The general rule, is that you might have different associations for different child models and different behaviour BUT you ALWAYS have all the table columns used by all child models.

The whole Idea for why you would want to use STI is that all models contain the same structure of data, but maybe have different behaviours. In your case, I would suggest using associations (as you suggested yourself) and then add the `has_one/has_many` in the child model, which would limit the associations scope within the inheritance chain.

It is not possible to restrict columns to only some child models without patching ApplicationRecord. But in any case, even if you manage to make a patch to introduce this kind of behaviour, your database table will still have all the columns for all the tables, thus resulting in bigger database tables due to half empty columns, increased size and reduced performance.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: i was only refering to this definition of inheritance https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html perhaprs rails has a different definition of inheritance from PostgreSQL

Comment: and what about CTI? http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/ClassTableInheritance.html

Comment: But as I understand you are talking about Rails implementation of STI, correct? The examples you presented are different concepts.

Comment: yes it's true i asked about STI but at the end of my question, i also asked if there is better solution, i'm just starting to understand the difference between STI and CTI.